# React redux async mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How come when calling `mapDispatchToProps` functions in `componentDidMount`, 
`mapStateToProps` `totalDoctorCount: state.doctors.totalDoctorCount` wont always load on time and I would get `undefined` result in `console.log("this.props.totalDoctorCount: "+this.props.totalDoctorCount );`.
I know it's the nature of `async`, but is there a way to fix it am i doing something wrong here.

Full Code :

doctorActions

```
export function getDoctors(filterType){
return function(dispatch){
    axios.get("/api/doctors/"+filterType)
        .then(function(response){
            dispatch({type:"GET_DOCTORS",payload:response.data});
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            dispatch({type:"GET_DOCTORS_REJECTED",payload:err});
        })
}
}

export function getTotalDoctors(){
return function(dispatch){
    axios.get("/api/getTotalDoctors/")
        .then(function(response){
            dispatch({type:"TOTAL_DOCTORS",payload:response.data});
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            //console.log(err);
            dispatch({type:"TOTAL_DOCTORS_REJECTED",payload:"there was an error rortal doctors"});
        })
}
}
```

doctorReducer

```
export function doctorsReducers(state={
doctors:[],
}, action){
switch(action.type){
    case "GET_DOCTORS":
    // return the state and copy of boos array from state
        return {...state,doctors:[...action.payload]}
    break;

    case "TOTAL_DOCTORS":
    // return the state and copy of boos array from state
        return {
            ...state,
            totalDoctorCount:action.payload
        }
    break;

}
return state;
}
```

server API

```
app.get('/doctors/:filterType',function(req,res){
let filterType = req.params.filterType;
var query = {};
if(filterType == "dateCreated"){
    query = {date_created: 'desc'};
}else if(filterType == "dateUpdated"){
    query = {date_updated: 'desc'};
}
Doctors.find({}).sort(query).limit(3).exec(function(err,doctors){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(doctors);
});
});

app.get('/getTotalDoctors',function(req,res){
Doctors.count({}, function(err, count){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(count);
});
});
```

component

```
class MainAdmin extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selected_filter:"dateCreated"
        };
    }

    openAddDoctorModal = () => {
        this.setState({AddDoctorModal:true});
    }

    closeAddDoctorModal = () => {
        this.setState({AddDoctorModal:false});
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getTotalDoctors();
        this.props.getDoctors(this.state.selected_filter);
    }



    loadPage = (pageNum) => {
        //alert(pageNum);
        this.props.loadPage(pageNum,this.state.selected_filter);
    }


    render(){

        const doctorsList = this.props.doctors.map(function(doctorsArr){
            return(
                <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} key={doctorsArr._id}>
                    <DoctorsItem
                        _id = {doctorsArr._id}
                        doc_fname = {doctorsArr.doc_fname}
                        doc_lname = {doctorsArr.doc_lname}
                    />
                </Col>
            )
        });

        //const lengthPage = parseInt(this.props.totalDoctorCount/3);
        console.log("this.props.totalDoctorCount2: "+this.props.totalDoctorCount );
        const pages = parseInt(this.props.totalDoctorCount/3, 10);
        console.log("pages: "+pages );

        const pageNums = [...Array(pages)].map((pageNum, i) => {
            return(
                <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2} key={i+1}>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.loadPage(i+1)} bsStyle="success" bsSize="small">
                        {i+1}
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            )
        });

        return(
            <Well>
                <Row style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>
                    {doctorsList}
                </Row>
                <Row style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>
                    {pageNums}
                </Row>
            </Well>
        )



    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        doctors: state.doctors.doctors,
        totalDoctorCount:state.doctors.totalDoctorCount
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        getDoctors:getDoctors,
        loadPage:loadPage,
        getTotalDoctors:getTotalDoctors
    },dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MainAdmin);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle this, but you must first understand how to handle asynchronous actions that affect your dom.

Whenever a component mounts (and depending on how you've set your app up, whenever a change is made to props, state, etc), its render function is called. In your example, the component mounts, then asks the server for the list of doctors, calls `render()`, and *then* receives the list of doctors from the server. To rephrase, by the time it called the render method, it has not yet received the list of doctors from the axios call.

Apologies if you understood all of this. Now for why `this.props.totalDoctorCount` is returning `undefined`: your app's `state.totalDoctorCount` is not being defined until the function `getTotalDoctors` resolves (i.e., hears back from server). You can fix this rather simply by defining `totalDoctorCount` as `0` in your `defaultState` (where you defined doctors as an empty array).

On the other hand, do you really want users to see/think that there are a total of `0` doctors until the server responds in time? This might be a good opportunity to consider a loading component. What I like to do is right below `render()`, check for the existence of whatever list you need to iterate through and if it is empty, you can return a `LoadingComponent` (you can make this on your own and use it wherever something needs to load).

This by itself is not enough, because you don't want the page to load indefinitely in the event that you actually don't have any doctors, so this `LoadingComponent` should only appear if the function that is retrieving the list that it's concerned with is still *'fetching'*. So perhaps you can implement three actions that are called before you fetch, after the fetch is responded to, and if there is an error.

### So to outline:

1) MainAdmin mounts.

2) `GetDoctors` and `GetTotalDoctors` are called.

3) A new action `isFetching` is called, leaving your state as:

```
{
    doctors: [],
    totalDoctors: 0, //assuming you have added this to defaultState
    isFetchingDoctors: true
}
```

4) `MainAdmin` calls `render()`.

5) since state.doctors is empty and `state.isFetchingDoctors` is `true`, `MainAdmin.render()` returns your new `LoadingComponent`.

6) Your server responds to your axios call with the list of doctors and the `totalDoctorCount` (note: this will happen at different times, but for sake of simplicity, I am treating them as happening together).

7) Your success handler updates your state with the new list of doctors:

```
{
    doctors: [1, 2, 3],
    totalDoctors: 3,
    isFetchingDoctors: true
}
```

8) `MainAdmin calls` `render()` again because of the change in state, but because `state.isFetchingDoctors` is still true, it will still show LoadingComponent.

8) Your second new action `isFetched()` is called, leaving your state as:

```
{
    doctors: [1, 2, 3],
    totalDoctors: 3,
    isFetchingDoctors: false
}
```

9) `MainAdmin` calls `render()` again, but this time the conditions to indicate that it is no longer loading are met, and you can safely iterate through your list of doctors.

One final note: You could also set isFetching to false in your reducer as soon as you `GetDoctors` but I personally like to separate the asynchronous status functions into their own function to keep to the motto of every function only tasked with doing one thing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information, if i got it right the componentDidMount() should look like this `componentDidMount(){this.props.isFetching();this.props.getTotalDoctors();this.props.getDoctors(this.state.selected_filter);this.props.isFetched(); } `     and render() should look like this     `render(){if( this.props.isFetchingDoctors === false && this.props.totalDoctorCount !== 0){return(){{doctorsList}}}else{return(){<Loader></Loader>}}`

Comment: Almost. This:

    this.props.isFetc‌​hed()

must only be called after this.getTotalDoctors resolves. So you can either pass it as a callback to this.getTotalDoctors:

    this.props.getTotalDoctors(function(response) { /* Handle response */ this.props.isFetched(); }

And then call the callback inside getTotalDoctors (after .then()).

Comment: it seems like this.props.isFetched(); is not getting executed

Comment: Do i need to change the doctorActions to take callbacks

Comment: Either use callbacks or Promises. If you want a single 'isFetching'/'isFetched' state property, then you need to make sure both getTotalDoctors() and getDoctors() are resolved before calling isFetched(). Alternatively, you can separate 'isFetching'/'isFetched' into something like 'isFetchingDoctors'/'isFetchingTotalDoctors', etc. Some components in your app might not need to wait for getting the total doctors, but might want to wait for getting doctors, etc. That said, here is a quick and dirty example of what I think should work for you: https://imgur.com/a/KZNkH